# MappedByteBuffer Scala/Java

Tags: scala, memory-mapped-files

I'm using a MappedByteBuffer in Scala (although this question is relevant to Java too) to open a file of roughly 400MB. Here's a code snippet:

```
val file = new java.io.File( ... )
val stream = new java.io.FileInputStream( file )
val buffer = stream.getChannel.map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, file.length )
```

However, this fails, with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file to required size
```

From what I've read, you should be able to map a file of up to 2GB. In terms of my JVM settings, I've got -Xmx4G set, so I can't see why it's unable to open the file. By way of a test, I mapped a smaller section of the file (~1mb), which worked correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd misread the example I'd seen online, assuming that the third argument to map was the byte of the file to stop reading, whereas actually it is the number of bytes to read. Changing this solves the problem.